# Linux command equivalent to 'ls' with -R argument?

Tags: command-line, ls, command

I am green to Linux. I was asked to implement a Linux command to list all files in directories without `ls` command and with `-R` argument.

I tried the below command:

```
dir -R
```

Which turns out it show all the subdirectories as well, not only the first level.

Is there any way to implement it? In my knowledge `-R` should list all the subdirectories but it need to list the first level only.

Comment: `dir` without any argument shows only the current directory level and all the files in there, that's what you seem to require? If you specify `-R` it will show all files and directories recursively.

Comment: yes, but it requires '-R' argument included in the command. thanks!

Comment: Does "implement a command with `-R` argument" mean you're supposed to write something yourself (without using `ls`) that _accepts_ a `-R` argument?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add more details. If you are supposed to create a command, show the expected syntax how your command can be called. Show an example of directories and files you have and the corresponding output you expect from your command.

Answer (score 1):

According to `dir`'s or `ls`'s manual:

> **-R, --recursive**
>
> list subdirectories recursively

If you use the `-R` flag it will show all files and directories recursively.

As [BarBar1234](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612313/413007) proposed you can use the `find` command to specify a depth parameter. An alternative is the `tree` with `-d` (print only directories) and `-L` (max level depth):

```
tree -L 1 -d
```

Output example:

```
.
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── dir3
```

---

If you really want a command that has a `-R` flag to list only the first level directories you can build one yourself using `find` for example:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    find .
elif [ "$1" = "-R" ]; then
    find . -type d -maxdepth 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | sort
```

Obviously the depth parameter will allow you to go as deep in the tree as necessary, and adding switches like `-type d` to only show directories, or `-type f` for just files will help you further narrow down your output.

Comment: thanks for reply, but any commands with '-R' argument would do as it is a part of requirement? cheers

Answer (score 0):

With bash:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
printf "%s\n" **
```

If you want to display hidden files and directories, add

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob
```

ref: [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in the manual